# Starting activity causes ViewPager to reset

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I asked this question previously and thought it was working and deleted the question, but since have found this isn't working.  I have a `ViewPager` in my app, with each `Fragment` of the `ViewPager` holding a `ListView`.  When an item in the `ListView` is selected, I am starting a new activity in `onListItemClick`:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    final Intent browser = new Intent(activity, Browser.class);

    startActivity(browser);
}
```

The problem is that when I press either the back button, or the Home button in the `Actionbar`, the `ViewPager` has reset itself to show the first fragment.

This is the code I'm using for the Home button:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) 
{
     if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

It was recommended, in my original question, to set the launch mode in the Android Manifest to `singleTop`, which I did for the startup activity as well as the activity launched from the `ListView`, but that didn't seem to fix it.

I thought about passing the `ViewPager's` position to the new activity, then retrieving it in `onResume` of the original activity and manually setting the `ViewPager's` position, but that seems really brute force to me.

Comment: Please don't delete questions only to re ask them later. If you want to attract attention on your question either edit it and add more details or post a bounty on it. The behavior you talk about seems rather strange especially if the BACK button also resets the `ViewPager`. Are you sure you don't have any other code in one of the lifecycle callbacks(or some attributes in the manifest file for the activities) that resets the position?

Comment: @Luksprog I'm an idiot.  I put code in `onResume` of the main `Activity` that reset the `ViewPager`, to fix a separate issue, which caused the result I was seeing in the OP.  I didn't actually delete the first post to get more attention, it was working, then it wasn't and it confused me, but now it's working.  Thanks.